# PowerShell Validation

Tags: powershell

> The error is : If The type of the user is a valid type like student or
> personnel the output said Invalid User
> >My code:

```
$EntrezN = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the username"
$EntrezP = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the first name"
$EntrezT = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the Type of the user"
$name = $EntrezN.length
$FirstName=$EntrezP.Length
echo $name
echo $FirstName

if ($name -gt 25 -or $name -lt 1 -or $FirstName -gt 25 -or $FirstName -lt 1)  { 
echo " Invalid user"
}



if($EntrezT -ne "student" -or $EntrezT -ne"Student" -or $EntrezT -ne"personnel" -or $EntrezT -ne "Personnel")  {echo "Invalid User"
}
else {echo "The user is good"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a function, then use ValidateSet on the parameters.
It's case-insensitive by default

e.g.

```
Function Do-Stuff
{
    Param(
        [ValidateSet('student','personnel')]
        [String]
        $EntrezT
    )
    Write-Host $EntrezT
}

Do-Stuff -EntrezT 'student'
```